# How to batch insert same clip scene at the beginning of multiple videos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, batch-processing, mencoder

I have been for a few days researching on a suitable auto or semi-automatic way of mass merging files this way. Basically, what I want to achieve is inserting the same clip, before a bunch of other clips.

In this case I´ve been trying with .flv, .mp4, .avi files (always merging same codecs), and I didn´t succeed after testing all the programs available in both Windows and OSx. Believe me, I´ve tried them all. The only ones which are supposed to handle quite well this quite of tasks are from Videocharge: *Watermark Master* and *Videocharge Studio*. None of them could perform correctly the task. Maybe there was some way I could have achieved this by scripting with *After Effects* or *Sony Vegas*, I just didn´t find any.

Now I´m trying to find some way to achieve the same thing either by shell, unix scripting... I don´t care. I just don´t want to mount Ubuntu only for these tasks. I´m not a programmer, but I´m quite stuborn (which sometimes leads me to neverending nights) so I would appreciate some help or guidance from anyone keen and good enough on batch video processing or scripting.

Right now, the only useful paths I´ve found drive me into either using **mencode** or **ffmpeg** through commands, but I am not able to perform the merge on batch. I don´t care about the way to sort the videos out. But taking into consideration that the operation would be performed on hundreds or thousands of videos, it wouldn´t be suitable to have them all in separate folders each accompanied by the "unique" intro clip. I guess that the most logic way would be storing the "bunch" videos in a folder, and the intro clip on the same folder as the encoder or renderer.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance,

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites. Duplicate of [How to batch insert same clip scene at the beginning of multiple videos?](http://superuser.com/q/605543/110524)

Comment: I didn´t even know that both sites were related. Thank´s for letting me know. I won´t duplicate posts any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command for a quick and dirty way of adding an intro. The player may show a dislocation at the join, or it may not play at all.  The two video segments really need to be the same resolution, bitrate, codecs, and joined by some tool which can generate the intermediate frames.

```
copy /b "header.flv" + "video.flv" "newvideo.flv"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip foxidrive. This is the only way I already managed to make it work. But I´m trying to find some way that I can insert the header in batch in all the videos. Apparently, there is some way to detail all the videos in one txt file and then running the above command in batch, but I can´t manage to make it work as I don´t know how to relate the command to the video (txt) database.

Comment: There should be some way to delete a comment.

Answer (score 0):

copy /b "header.flv" + "video.flv" "newvideo.flv" doesn´t seem to work, as though the codec is the same (FLV1), the resolution differs a  little in some videos.

I´ve tried different variations:

for %a in ("*.flv") do Mencoder -oac copy "c:\INTRO.flv" "%a" -o "c:\TEMP\%a"

for %a in ("*.flv") do Mencoder -forceidx -of lavf -oac copy -ovc copy -o "c:\TEMP\%a" "c:\INTRO.flv" "%a"

I don´t know if I should try with ffmpeg, I´m pretty sure that this can be achieved without the need to reencode, as I have tested several programs and none of them are reencoding, they are just forcing the resolution in some cases. In fact, the program that seemed to behave the best was the AIR application Rich Flv, but it doesn´t work on batch.